# Ito's lemma in infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to use the ito's lemma in infinite dimensional spaces applicatte to $F(X)=\Vert AX\Vert^{2}$, where $A$ is a linear map. But i I have trouble calculating the integral

$\int_{0}^{t}\langle F_{x}(s,X_{s}), \Phi(s)dW_{s}\rangle$ and $\int_{0}^{t}\langle F_{x}(s,X_{s}), \varphi(s)\rangle ds$

where

$X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\varphi(s)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\Phi(s)dW_{s}$

(see https://books.google.cl/books/about/Stochastic_Equations_in_Infinite_Dimensi.html?id=JYiL8zz_nC8C&redir_esc=y, Theorem 4.32)

and i don't know what to do =(
Please help!

Comment: In the book after the proof of this theorem there is a worked example with $F(x) = \|x\|^2$, did you have a look at it? What issues are you having here?